# Perl "Use of uninitialized value"

Tags: perl

#### Perl script

```
my ($directory) = @ARGV; #"www"

if ( not defined $directory ) {
    die "ERROR";
}

if ( defined $directory ) {

    print "Yes or No ? (y/n) : ";
    my $terminer = <>; 
    chomp $terminer;

    if ( $terminer eq "o" ) {       
        print "OK";     
    }
    elsif ( $terminer eq "n" ) {
        ##########
    }
}
```

An error message appears:

> Use of uninitialized value $terminer in scalar chomp at test.pl
> Use of uninitialized value $terminer in string eq at test.pl

Can you help me?

Comment: Your "Hello" was disappearing because greetings in general are removed from questions automatically. See [this answer on *Meta*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/93989/170274) from **Jeff Atwood**. I've also removed a lot of other unnecessary junk from your question. Your job is to *communicate the problem* and nothing else; this isn't a social chat site.

Answer (score 6):

When reading from empty angle brackets, `<>`, Perl reads from the files supplied in `@ARGV` if there are any. But you didn't have a file there: it was a directory name.

You copy an entry in `@ARGV` to `$directory` but also leave it in `@ARGV`. Then, further down in your code, `my $terminer = <>` tries to read from the *"file"* (that you have in `@ARGV` as the directory).

A fix could be either `my $directory = shift @ARGV` which should empty `@ARGV` and let you read keyboard input from the empty brackets further on in your code.

Or you could write `my $terminer= <STDIN>`, so that Perl will read only from the keyboard and not from the files listed in the `@ARGV` array.

Comment: Either way, should check if `$terminer` is undef, which can still happen with these fixes.

Comment: Also check that there is only one parameter passed in `@ARGV`.

Comment: <STDIN> fixed the problem !!

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can also do the following:

```
chomp(my $terminar = <STDIN>);
```

Comment: <STDIN> is not displaying there after = .